# Dealing with Time in an HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

Ok. I am working on a Program Schedule Manager for my internet radio station. I have come thus far but can't seem to figure out dealing with the Air Time and End Time of show when editing. Below is the code from the form.

The times are stored in the HTML database as 24-hour format to make sorting easier.

If you need to look at the rest of the code: https://github.com/phillf/ProgramScheduleManager

Code from: admin/editShow.php:

```
    <td>What time does this show start?</td>
    <td>
        <select name="AirTime">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am' ?></option>
        <?php endfor ?>
        </select>
    </td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>What time does the show end?</td>
    <td>
        <select name="EndTime">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am' ?></option>
        <?php endfor ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please describe what the exact problem is.

Comment: "Dealing" how? Doing what?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to select the AirTime and End Time based upon the data returned from the the database in the dropdown.

Comment: maybe use a timepicker plugin such as http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: Are you just asking how to make the current value the default selected item in the dropdown?

Comment: Ok so my other comment didn't get posted??? @Barmar Yes. That is exactly what am asking.

Comment: Your comment didn't make this clear. Anyway, see the answer. There's nothing special about times in this regard, you do it the same way as any other menu where you want to default to the current value from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've done a database query and put the current air time in `$airTime`, you set the `selected` attribute like this:

```
<select name="AirTime">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
         <option value="<?= $i; ?>:00:00" <?php if ($i == $airTime) { echo 'selected'; } ?> ><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am' ?></option>
    <?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

And similarly for `EndTime`.

Comment: I am going to truest that the code above works. How ever I am now having an issue with it saving the times properly. When it saves the times it appears to be saving the like: 00:00:21 for example, which should actually be 21:00:00

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the way you format the time when you create the `UPDATE` query. Start a new question and show how you do this.

Comment: I looked at your scheduler class, and added `:00:00` to the value attributes. I think that should solve the problem. Or you could change the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements in the scheduler class.